# Death Stranding Doesn't Open

Tags: epic-games-launcher, death-stranding

I have just bought and installed **Death Stranding** on Epic Games Launcher. Unfortunately cannot play it. When I launch it, it changes its status to "Playing" for a few seconds, but nothing else happens.

That's it.

I made sure my Windows 10 is up-to-date. My GPU drivers are too. I have the latest redistributable installed.

I googled event viewer's logs and spent a few hours trying different type of wizardry but nothing worked for me.

I've run out of options and not sure what else I can do, so turning to you guys as experts on the topic. Perhaps one of you have experienced anything similar in the past.

Thanks in advance. Any help is much appreciated.